# Why doesn't the new-component wizard display any ancestor classes?

Tags: delphi, ide, c++builder, vcl

I'm trying to create new VCL component in RAD Studio XE2. I got the same result using C++ Builder or Delphi:

[image: New-component wizard displaying no ancestors]

How do I get the list of VCL components? I tried "repair setup," but no success.

Comment: What's that Wizard supposed to do? I've never seen it! I don't think you need it.

Comment: @CosminPrund: Really? It's been there for quite a while. I just checked Delphi 4 on my Windows 95 machine, and the same functionality is found there, but not in the form of a 'wizard'. Rather, it's a simple dialog box. Still, you don't need it.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, probably decided a long time ago there's nothing worth clicking in the `Component` menu. Except "Install Packages", and only for troubleshooting.

Comment: Well, I need to develop VCL component, so I guess I need it :)

Comment: @Tracer: No, you don't need it.

Comment: It takes more time to use this wizard to create a new component than it does to just write the raw code. I've used this wizard once in my life in Delphi 7, and realized right away how unnecessary it is. However, if this wizard is still available in Delphi, then surely it should work.

Comment: My guess is that maybe you're using a washed down version of Delphi which does not include the base source code, and that this particular screen expects these components to come with source? Still I don't believe it though.

Comment: To create a new component, 1. Create a new package, 2. Write your component, 3. Register the component, 4. Install the package.

Comment: @Jerry, I own RAD Studio XE2 Professional, so it's not some "washed down" version. But anyway, I'll try manually creating a package (what David suggested). Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

That happens when your list of design-time packages is empty. So, somehow I guess you have lost your design-time packages. Restore them like this:

1. From the menu select **Component | Install Packages**.
2. If you see anything in the list, check, at the very least, **Embarcadero Standard Components**.
3. If **Embarcadero Standard Components** is not in the list, click Add and browse to the Delphi bin directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin).
4. Once there, select **dclstd160.bpl**.
5. Also add any other packages that you need. You may wish to include more than just the standard components.

At this point the **New Component** dialog will start offering you some ancestor components.

Comment: So you can add standard components to an empty form?

Comment: Yes. I can use all components. They are all listed and checked in "installed packages" but dont see them when trying to create new vcl component..

Comment: Perhaps you need to contact Emba. I can't think of any other explanation than the one above.

Comment: @Tracer have you tried re-installing Delphi? I know its not something everyone wants to have to do but it may be an option worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still have not solved the problem, it seems that the PowerPDF Package inhibits listing of ancestors. (for unknown reasons)
If you have installed it, try temporarily disabling it in Component/Installed packages (uncheck the PowerPDF Design-time package).
Magically, all your ancestors will reappear....:-)